# how can I remove with specific tags from html

Tags: c#, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)

I have html code below:

```
<div><span class="help">This is text.</span>Hello, this is text.</div>
<div>I have a question.<span class="help">Hi</span></div>
```

Now, I want to remove text which is between `<span class="help"></span>` using C#. So, I want to leave only

```
<div>Hello, this is text.</div>
<div>I have a question.</div>
```

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use  [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to work with html.

```
string text = @"<div><span class=""help"">This is text.</span>Hello, this is text.      </div>
                <div>I have a question.<span class=""help"">Hi</span></div>";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(text);
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='help']");
foreach( HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
   node.Remove();
} 
String result = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the idea to use `Html Agility Pack` to parse html.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);  // this is your string
var divs = doc.DocumentNode.Elements("div")
      .Select(div => string.Format("<div>{0}</div>", div.LastChild.InnerText));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex

```
    string val = @"<div><span class=""help"">This is text.</span>Hello, this is text.</div><div>I have a question.<span class=""help"">Hi</span></div>";
        Regex reg = new Regex("<span .+?</span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        string ret = reg.Replace(val, "");
        Debug.WriteLine(ret);
```

Comment: -1: Don't use a regex to parse html

Comment: why? I would think it is faster than parse html.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score -2):

get the elements to contain the runat="server" so they can be accessed from the codebehind and then when it is suitable try getting the element by its id name and do either 
element.innerHTML = ""; or element.innerText = "";

Comment: sorry but how do you -1 the comment? this does what you want to do

Comment: I am appreciated with your comment. But as you can see, I was meaning to handle html strings.

Comment: well then you should have said so in the description. dont expect everyone to just guess what you want.

Comment: sorry bro~ it was all my mistake. please do not get pissed on me.

Comment: Drakoumel, you have a tendency to come off very aggressive and defensive. Would suggest actual communication.